# Is it possible to define custom function types in Typescript

Tags: typescript, interface, casting

```
const obj: Person = { first: 'John', last: 'Thomas'};
interface Person {
first: string;
last: string;
}
```

To specify an object has first and last property, we specify it as type Person, is there similar feature available for function in Typescript For ex.

```
const Fun1:(p:Person)=>void = (p) => {
    console.log('first function',JSON.stringify(p))
}

const Fun2:(p:Person)=>void = (p) => {
    console.log('second function',JSON.stringify(p))
}

console.log(Fun1(obj))
console.log(Fun2(obj))
```

Fun1 and Fun2 are functions of same type, so can we define some type in TypeScript like this

```
type Function1 = (p:Person)=> void

const Fun1:Function1 = (p) => {
    console.log('first function',JSON.stringify(p))
}

const Fun2:Function1 = (p) => {
    console.log('second function',JSON.stringify(p))
}

console.log(Fun1(obj))
console.log(Fun2(obj))
```

Comment: What was wrong with the code above? What didn't work? It looks to be to be syntaxly correct?

`type SomeFunction =
  (arg1: string, arg2: number, ...args: any[]) => void;`

Comment: My question is that, whether it is possible to write block 3 as an optimization for block 2

Comment: My answer would be kind of, when testing locally I could use your block 3 code, requiring the correct signature on the method call, it doesn't require the correct signature on the function declaration though.

Example: this is completely valid: `const fun1: Function1 = () => {}` which makes sense in a way, as this would allow for overloaded functions.

Even without types specified I still get type hinting / type errors when trying to use different types so yes, I feel (if I understand you correctly), you can use the block 3 in place of block 2, in my opinion block 3 is more readable.

Comment: Thank you @Isolated, yes, I also confirmed it works! I had just written it out of curiosity

Comment: So what's the question here? 

Comment: question is same, answer be how to write custom function types, and thus we can explain same in answer

Comment: @AkshayVijayJain it's always worth checking out if there's a better approach to something, or even just getting validation on your approach so no problem there, I personally prefer block 3, of course this is all opinion as it's all compiled down to JavaScript anyway.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is possible to define custom function types in Typescript through following two ways
First way:
 `type SomeFunction = (arg1: string, arg2: number) => void;`
Second Way:

```
interface SomeFunction {
(arg1:string, arg2:number):void
}
```

And then we can use this custom function type while defining functions as follows

```
const newFunction:SomeFunction = (arg1,arg2) => { console.log(arg1,arg2) }
```